# How to find the max of $|e^x-1-\frac 32x|$ on $[0, 1]$ more rigorously?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I have to find 
$$\max_{x \in [0, 1]}\left|e^x-1-\frac 32x\right| = \max_{x \in [0, 1]} f(x) $$
To do this, I of course have to check the endpoints of the interval, the points where the derivative is zero, and the point(s) where the derivative is undefined.

From the graph, it is clear what to do.

[image]

I have to find where the derivative of $-\left( e^x-1-\dfrac{3}{2}x \right) $ is zero, and then check it against $f(1)$. But how can I do this completely rigorously?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's mean *more rigorously*?

Comment: @Azif00 For example, I assumed that the critical point occured where the graph is below the $x$ axis, so I looked at the derivative of $-(e^x-1-\frac 32x)$, rather than the derivative of $e^x-1-\frac 32x$. But I justified this based on the graph, not on rigor. Also, it is "obvious" that where the derivative is undefined, $f$ will be zero, but I did not prove this (though I think I can prove this if I think about it, I will try it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "rigorously" you mean without using a graphing calculator to graph it then one thing you can do is prove that the function $g(x)=e^x-1-\frac{3}{2}x$ has the properties illustrated by the graph which allow you to conclude that you only need to check the endpoints and the point where the derivative is zero. To be more specific, one way you could do this would be to:

1. Prove that if $x<\ln(1.5)$ then $g'(x)<0$ (so g strictly decreasing) and if $x>\ln(1.5)$ then $g'(x)>0$ (so g strictly increasing).
2. Prove that $g(\ln(1.5)) < 0$ (might help to use fact that $e<2.72$), $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)>0$ (might help to use fact that $2.7<e$).
3. From $g(x)$ continuous, 1., and 2. conclude that $g(x)$ has exactly two zeros call them $x_0$ and $x_1$ such that $x_0=0$ and $\ln(1.5) < x_1 < 1$.
4. From the preceding you can conclude that if $x < x_0$ then $g(x) > 0$, if $x_0 < x < x_1$ then $g(x) < 0$ and if $x_1 < x$ then $g(x) > 0$. Therefore, since $f(x) = |g(x)|$,
   $$f(x) = \begin{cases} g(x) & \impliedby x \in (-\infty, x_0] \cup [x_1, \infty) \\ 
   -g(x) & \impliedby x \in [x_0, x_1] \end{cases}.$$ 
   Furthermore, $x_0$ and $x_1$ are all of the points at which the derivative of $f$ are undefined, but you also know $f(x_0) = f(x_1) = 0$ and there is at least one $x \in [0, 1]$ such that $f(x) > 0$ and so neither of $x_0$ or $x_1$ can be points at which the maximum occurs.
5. From 1. and 2. you know that $g$ has a global minimum at $\ln(1.5)$ and so $-g$ has a global maximum at $\ln(1.5)$. Therefore, from 4., you know that on the interval $[x_0, x_1]$ the largest value of $f$ occurs at $\ln(1.5)$. You also know that $f(x_1)=0$ and $f$ is increasing on $[x_1, \infty]$ (since f=g on that interval), and so the maximum $f$ can achieve on $[x_1, 1]$ occurs at $1$.
6. Make your original conclusion that you only need to check $f(\ln(1.5))$ against $f(1)$.

Comment: Thanks! ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=|g(x)|, g(x)=e^x-1-3x/2, x\in [0,1] \implies g'(x)=e^x-3/2$$ $$ \implies x_0=\ln(3/2)=0.4050...<1.$$
So $f(x)$ has a maximunm at $x_0<1$ and $f(x_0)=1/2-3\ln(3/2)=0.1081$.., but the value od $f(1)=e-1-3/2=0.2182...$ So this is the global maximum  of $f(x)$. However, there is a local max. at $x=x_0$ of value 0.1081....
See  $f(x)$ in the Fig.below
[image]